# Ext , Grid , scrolling after edit cell with RTL

Tags: jquery, grid, scrollbar, right-to-left, ext.net

I have a RTL webpage with a Ext.Net c# Grid control. I allow scrolling for the grid.
This all works fine. After I change value of a cell in  RTL "Ext grid" , scroll bar lose correct size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way to fix it.
Call this function after edit a cell in grid.

```
function FixScrollSize(gridClientID) 
{
    $("[id=" + gridClientID + "] .x-grid-editor").hide();
}
```